# Eliminate duplicates in select with php

Tags: php, sql, select

I want to eliminate all the duplicates in a select dropdown list created with PHP.

My PHP code that creates the dropdown list is the following:

```
public static function getDropdownlist($conn)
{
    //Initialize dropdown list
    //--------------------------------------------------
    $ddl_query = "select * from MIS_EMPLOYEES";
    $stmt_ddl = oci_parse($conn, $ddl_query);
    oci_execute($stmt_ddl);
    //A default value -- this will be the selected item in the dropdown ##
    $prosopiko = JRequest::getVar('bodies', 0);
    if ($prosopiko == 0)
        $default = 0;
    else  
        $default = $prosopiko;
    //Initialize array to store dropdown options ##

      $options = array();
     // $options = array_unique();
      $options[] = JHTML::_('select.option', '0', 'Επιλέξτε');
      while (($row = oci_fetch_array($stmt_ddl, OCI_ASSOC+OCI_RETURN_NULLS)) != false) {
        $options[] = JHTML::_('select.option', $row['ID'], $row['POSITION']);
      }

    //Create <select name="month" class="inputbox"></select> ##
      $dropdown = JHTML::_('select.genericlist', $options, 'bodies', 'class="inputbox"', 'value', 'text', $default);

      return $dropdown; 
   }

}
```

But it brings all the duplicates written from an Oracle table.

How can I eliminate the duplicates? I tried `array_unique` but I failed.

Comment: show your array here on which you applied `array_unique`.

Comment: This isn't really a PHP problem, it's a you-need-a-different-query problem. Change the query to return `ID` and `POSITION` from  `MIS_EMPLOYEES` grouped by `ID` and `POSITION` (to get distinct combinations). You're probably returning more information than you need with that query the way it is (`SELECT *` is a code smell).

Comment: Please modify your query instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your SQL statement, simply change it to gather distinct elements you are interested in.

Since you are only using two values in the above code for the value and text, something like this should work:

```
SELECT ID, POSITION
FROM MIS_EMPLOYEES
GROUP BY ID, POSITION
```

Comment: Thank you both for the answer the second was closer and the solution is the following i changed the line,

from

     $ddl_query = "select * from MIS_EMPLOYEES";

to

   $ddl_query = "SELECT POSITION FROM MIS_EMPLOYEES GROUP BY POSITION";

once again thank you

Answer (score 3):

Easiest option is to modify your query to `SELECT DISTINCT ID, POSITION` or `GROUP BY ID, POSITION`. Other than that you'll need to build up an array and use `array_unique` on that.